# Handling of error : program run from shell doesnt return

Tags: bash, shell

I have a shell script which updates different firmwares with different executables.
I need to know if one of the executable has hung and not returning back to shell.
Can I introduce any kind of timeout ?

Sample shell script below. How to handle if updatefw command hangs and does not return.

```
#!/bin/sh

updatefw -c config.cfg
    if [ $? != 0 ]; then
        echo "exec1 failed"
        exit 1   
    fi  
exit 0
```

Comment: `sh` is usually not `bash`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest with [timeout](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/coreutils.html#timeout-invocation) from GNU core utilities:

```
#!/bin/bash

timeout 30 updatefw -c config.cfg
if [[ $? == 124 ]]; then
  echo "update failed"
  exit 1
fi
```

When `timeout` quits `updatefw`, the return code is 124.

I assume here that the update will never take longer than 30 seconds.